# Indent report details (authors, contacts,..) in the same way

Tags: report

I would like to recreate the details below from a Word template in LaTeX. I have tried using the code below but it has not given the correct results.

[image]

I have tried using the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\newpage

\noindent Cover Photo: 
\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5cm}{Cover Photo: }{Photographer}

\end{adjustwidth}

\\

\noindent Report Authors: 
\begin{adjustwidth}{2.5cm}{}
Author 1, Author 2, Author 3
\end{adjustwidth}

\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try the `description` environment.